# How to create a dropdown menu without messing up the rest of the code....?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked before probably a million times, but I can't seem to find an answer or solution that fits my exact situation or code. (If there is one, please link me!)

I'm just trying to create a simple dropdown menu on a horizontal navigation that has a logo image centered with links on either side. I do have bootstrap installed, but I can't seem to figure out a simple way to code it using their framework, so I said screw it and built this one from scratch.

It doesn't necessarily have to be straight html/css, but I'm not super familiar with js (still learning).

Here's my current code:

```css
#header {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 80px auto 0;
}

#header ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#header ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 97px;
}

#header ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-left: 217px;
}

#header ul li a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    height: 28px;
    color: #000;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}

#header ul li a:hover {
    color: #c4c4c4;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -60px 0 0 -124px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .logo {
    bottom: 100%;
  }

  #header ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  #header ul {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <a class="logo"><img src="http://www.susanhudsonphotography.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/p4/images/logo_1368744984.jpg" alt="Whatever Photography" height="140" width="230" /></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Galleries <span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                <ul class="sub-menu"> <!--if you comment out the sub-menu, you'll see the navigation as I want it to look-->
                    <li><a href="">Portraits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Landscapes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Personal</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Info/Rates</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Prints</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Another problem I'm encountering is that when I resize my viewport to a mobile size, the logo image moves to the top of the nav links and half of it is hidden out of view. Though that's a whole separate issue...

Comment: I recommend you use jQuery for this.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modified your code a bit, you could try something like this.

```css
#header {
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 80px auto 0;
}

#header ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#header ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 97px;
}

#header ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-left: 217px;
}

#header ul li a {
    text-transform: lowercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 12px 0 0 0;
    height: 28px;
    color: #000;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}

#header ul li a:hover {
    color: #c4c4c4;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -60px 0 0 -124px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .logo {
    bottom: 100%;
  }

  #header ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  #header ul {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
    ul.sub-menu { 
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: auto!important;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0 1em;
        z-index: 2;
        background: white;
        
    }
    
    .sub-menu li { display: block; float: none!important; }
    
    .more { position: relative; }
    .more:hover .sub-menu { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<div id="header">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li class="more"><a href="">Galleries <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Portraits</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Landscapes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Personal</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
            <li>        <a class="logo"><img src="http://www.susanhudsonphotography.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/p4/images/logo_1368744984.jpg" alt="Whatever Photography" height="140" width="230" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="">Info/Rates</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Prints</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I just changed the value of top under the ul.sub-menu to 30 so that you can still see 'galleries' on hover.